# Disable touchpad by registry in dell inspiron 13-5379

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have a dell inspiron 13-5379
You can see which drivers i can download here
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/0-dWtRb0NxZ0V1UFNzNTliVm9RVzlsQT090/drivers

I don't find a driver download for the touchpad, the current driver used is the windows 2006 default that throws an error, so the touchpad can only move and be clicked.

Windows settings for touchpad are almost empty because driver is broken, so can't disable it from there.

I want to disable it to be able to write in the keyboard without having to worry to click or move the mousepad.

Tried already with drivers and else, so iam searching if i can do it with the registry.

Comment: You could try to force-install an incompatible driver, even of another device. This will disable it.

Comment: I would ask over here, they may be able to dog one up for you....https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/bd-p/Inspiron

Comment: @Moab i don't have that folder in my regedit(Synaptics)

Comment: Look for a different name for the touchpad other than Synaptics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open registry editor and navigate to this key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh

(I may have a name different than Synaptics like Alps)

right click the empty space and choose New > DWORD (32-bit Value)

> DisableIntPDFeature

Select Hexadecimal option and change the Value data to 33. Click OK

Close Registry Editor and restart your PC

After making these changes in the registry, you should see the option to disable your touchpad in Mouse settings

Other than this you may not be able to do it in the registry since it is using a generic driver with no software installed, another solution is to disable it in **Device Manger**

.

[Source](https://windowsreport.com/disable-touchpad-mouse-connected-windows-10/#3)

Comment: Maybe i have the generic driver, but can't disable in the device manager either.

Comment: Just for the record, besides doing this my boss punched the pad, so, idk which of these things did it, but the pad stopped working.

Comment: A real nice Boss....